# asyncio tasks are launched only after asyncio.sleep is invoked

Tags: python, python-asyncio

The worker tasks in the following example get executed only after `await asyncio.sleep` has been invoked. Is there any way to get the workers launched straight after creation without having to sleep?

```
 import asyncio
    import random
    import time
    
    async def worker(name, queue):
        print(f"starting worker {name}")
        while True:
            sleep_for = await queue.get()
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_for)
            queue.task_done()
            print(f'{name} has slept for {sleep_for:0.2f} seconds')
    
    async def main(n):
        queue = asyncio.Queue()
        total_sleep_time = 0
        for _ in range(20):
            sleep_for = random.uniform(0.05, 1.0)
            total_sleep_time += sleep_for
            await queue.put(sleep_for)
        tasks = []
        for i in range(n):
            task = asyncio.create_task(worker(f'worker-{i}', queue))
            tasks.append(task)
        started_at = time.monotonic()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.00001)
        await queue.join()
        total_slept_for = time.monotonic() - started_at
        for task in tasks:
            task.cancel()
        # Wait until all worker tasks are cancelled.
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        print('====')
        print(f'3 workers slept in parallel for {total_slept_for:.2f} seconds')
        print(f'total expected sleep time: {total_sleep_time:.2f} seconds')
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        n = 3 if len(sys.argv) == 1 else sys.argv[1]
        asyncio.run(main(4))
```

Comment: asyncio using cooperative multitasking. There is only one thing running at a time. You have to yield control back to the event loop in order for the next thing to have a turn.

Comment: thanks @dirn. Is there any other way of yielding control back to the event loop without having to sleep?

Comment: Awaiting an operation that performs I/O is another way. It’s really what asyncio was made for.